# Is it possible to use a Javascript variable within C# code inside HTML?

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays

I have a collection that I would like to iterate over, which is held in a C# variable.

I would like to iterate over this using a for loop from within Javascript; is this possible?

For example:

```
@{ int questionCount = 0;
foreach(var q in Model.Questions){ 
questionCount++;
}
```

...do some HTML...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {


for (var i=1;i<=@questionCount;i++)
{        

    var d1 = @Model.Questions[i].Answers.Where(m => m.Answer == 1).Count(); 
    <-- this is where it breaks -->
}

});
```

The error I get says that the index is out of range.  I guess this means that it doesn't understand 'i' once I've put the @ symbol into the line.  How can I delimit the string correctly to use the variable i (from Javascript) to iterate over my C# collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work. You cannot access client-side variables in a server-side code block.

Comment: As I thought, thanks for the confirmation.  Since I *can* ask for something like var d1 = @Model.Questions[0].Answers.Where(m => m.Answer == 1).Count(); (i.e. set the index to zero), and since I know the value of that index (from within the loop), is there a way to construct this single line dynamically?

Comment: You can create some code to run on the server that generates JavaScript (i.e., code that will then run on the client) in a string, then you output that string in your .CSHTML.

Comment: That sounds promising.  I'm a bit of a newbie to this stuff, would it be C# code that generates Javascript?

Comment: Yes, C# that generates a string that contains JavaScript. You then output that string in your HTML, for instance by displaying a property `@Model.GeneratedCode` or whatever you wish to call it.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon.  I'm just getting the script printing in plain text on screen.  If I paste this into the .cshtml file then reload, it works.  Any ideas why the javascript is just printing in plain text?

Comment: Do you output it somewhere in an HTML element that expects text? Or do you put it in the <HEAD> section between <script>...</script> tags?

Comment: Sorry for slow response; I fixed the problem with @Html.Raw(Model.Script), where Model.Script is the generated <script> tags.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for slow response; I fixed the problem with @Html.Raw(Model.Script), where Model.Script is the generated <script> tags.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for slow response; I fixed the problem with @Html.Raw(Model.Script), where Model.Script is the generated <script> tags.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not use server side models in your `javascript`, These models are relevant only on server side for generating `HTML`.

If you really need a value in your `javascript` code then you can put the model's value in some hidden `html` element.

Comment: Thanks @Asif; can you elaborate on your second sentence?  Also, Since I can ask for something like var d1 = @Model.Questions[0].Answers.Where(m => m.Answer == 1).Count(); (i.e. set the index to zero), and since I know the value of that index (from within the loop), is there a way to construct this single line dynamically?